# KeyError: 0 using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, keyerror

I have the following code inwhich I try to call a function compute_cluster which do some computations and write the results in a txt file (each process write its results in different txt files independently), however, when I run the following code:

```
def main():
  p = Pool(19)
  p.map(compute_cluster, [(l, r) for l in range(6, 25) for r in range(1, 4)]) 
  p.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

it crashes with the following errors:

```
File "RMSD_calc.py", line 124, in <module>
  main()                
File "RMSD_calc.py", line 120, in main
  p.map(compute_cluster, [(l, r) for l in range(6, 25) for r in range(1, 4)]) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 225, in map
  return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 522, in get
  raise self._value
  KeyError: 0
```

and when I searched online for the meaning of "KeyError: 0" i didn't find anything helpful so any suggestions why this error happens is highly appreciated

Comment: `KeyError` is the general error for when you try to dereference an item like a dictionary e.g. `x[1]`, but the index (i.e. `1`) isn't in the dictionary. But that doesn't really explain what's dereferencing a dictionary there.

Comment: What's the header of `compute_cluster()` and what does this function return?

Comment: Somewhere in `compute_cluster()` you have a `KeyError`. Maybe you are using a dict incorrectly? We can't tell where, unless you add the code for `compute_cluster()` tool also. The fact that the function runs in another process makes it a bit harder to debug. From the traceback it _looks_ like the error comes from multiprocessing, but most likely it is a problem in the passed function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KeyError` happens in `compute_cluster()` in a child process and `p.map()` reraises it for you in the parent:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(args):
    d = {}
    d[0] # <-- raises KeyError

if __name__=="__main__":
    p = Pool()
    p.map(f, [None])
```

#### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raise-exception-in-child.py", line 9, in <module>
    p.map(f, [None])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
KeyError: 0
```

To see the full traceback, catch the exception in the child process:

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(args):
    d = {}
    d[0] # <-- raises KeyError

def f_mp(args):
    try:
        return f(args)
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("f(%r) failed" % (args,))

if __name__=="__main__":
    p = Pool()
    p.map(f_mp, [None])
```

#### Output

```
ERROR:root:f(None) failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raise-exception-in-child.py", line 10, in f_mp
    return f(args)
  File "raise-exception-in-child.py", line 6, in f
    d[0] # <-- raises KeyError
KeyError: 0
```

It shows that `d[0]` caused the exception.